# AcroPdfLib to temporarily rotate a page

Tags: vb.net, pdf, rotation, acrobat, viewer

I have a VB.NET app which hosts an Adobe Acrobat Viewer through the AcroPdfLib.dll. It works great but most of our PDFs require a rotation to view properly. **Note that this is only for viewing and not saving or editing the PDF.** Even with Adobe Reader there is a menu available "Rotate Clockwise" that you can use to temporarily rotate the PDF in the viewer.

I can set certain properties for the viewer but cant seem to figure out how to rotate a page for viewing. Is there a function in AcroPdfLib.dll that I can use to rotate a page only for viewing?

```
        Dim IsLoaded As Boolean = acroPdf.LoadFile(pdfFile)
        If Not IsLoaded Then Throw New Exception("The PDF file failed to load.")

        acroPdf.setShowToolbar(True) 'displays the toolbar
        acroPdf.setPageMode("none") 'turn off the navigation panel on left side
        acroPdf.setLayoutMode("SinglePage")  'display one page at a time
```

Comment: As you are showing the toolbar, the use can right-click the toolbar and select "Show Page Display Tools" and add the "ClockWise" and "CounterClockWise" buttons.

Comment: Yes the menu is available. I want to do it programatically.